# Alfresco - Download statistics and user permissions report

Tags: download, statistics, reporting, alfresco, alfresco-share

Hey to every alfresco pro out there!
Is there any way to create a report (graphical or textually, i don't care) to see the following information:

- download count per file
- how many times did user X download a specific file
- which permissions do the users have

Are my goals easy to realize? Is there any plugin out there that i can use for this? (Already searched for some but couldn't find one) Hope that you can help me :)

mtzE

Comment: For the somewhat OOTB solution, your best chance is the AAAR (https://addons.alfresco.com/addons/alfresco-audit-analysis-and-reporting-aaar). Other then that, you're on your own.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing out-of-the-box that is counting downloads. Maybe the audit service can be used to count reads, but you'll have to turn it on and configure it. Once turned on, the audit service writes records to a set of audit tables in your Alfresco database. You can then use any reporting tool to query those tables.

If you want to check the permissions a user has you can use something like OpenCMIS to connect to the repository, traverse a folder path, and then, for each object, you can inspect the ACL of that object to use as data in your report.

As Lista said, one way to create such reports is to use AAAR, but that is not required.